# Geometric distribution after $n$ trials

Tags: probability-distributions

> Find the probability of $x$ happening for the first time after $n = 1000$ trials with $p = 0.001$

So after $n$, I'm assuming that this means at most $n$? I know the generic way of solving at most which would be:

$$p(0) + p(1) + \cdots + p(n)$$

but without using $\sigma$ how would I find the sum for a large $n$?

Comment: Hint:  saying that the first hit occurs after $n$ trials just means that the first $n$ trials were all misses.

Comment: There seems to be an ambiguity in the question -- I would have interpreted it to mean that x happens for the first time exactly after $n$ trials, whereas @lulu seems to have interpreted it to mean "after at least $n$ trials".

Comment: @joriki That is indeed how I read it, though revisiting the question I think I might agree that your reading is more likely.  To be clear, you think the first hit is meant to occur on the $(n+1)^{st}$ trial or on the $n^{th}$?

Comment: @lulu: I would have thought on the $n$-th, but I agree it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion between @joriki and myself in the comments:

The question is somewhat ambiguous.  It could mean (at least) one of three things:

I.  The first $n$ trials are all misses (no condition on what comes after).

II.  The first hit occurs on the $n^{th}$ trial (so that the first $n-1$ trials are all misses and the $n^{th}$ is a hit).

III.  The first hit occurs on the $(n+1)^{st}$ trial (so that the first $n$ trials are all misses and the $(n+1)^{st}$ is a hit).

No way to resolve the ambiguity (other than going back to the original source for clarification).  But the solutions are fairly similar.  Let $p$ be the probability of a hit and $q=1-p$ be the probability of a miss. (in the OP $p=.001$ but we can work in general with no extra effort).

The probability of two independent events both occurring is the product of the individual probabilities.  Hence:

I. the probability is $q^n$.

II. the probability is $q^{n-1}p$.

III. the probability is $q^{n}p$.